# Why is my compareTo() giving false answers?

Tags: java, compareto

Here is a bit of my code its a for loop to create an ordered list of strings a but for some reason its giving a false answer on one of the numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> answer = new ArrayList();
    List<String> n = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = 1327;
    int x = 17;
    int y = 15;
    int z = 12;
    n.add(Integer.toString(x));
    n.add(Integer.toString(y));
    n.add(Integer.toString(z));
    n.add(Integer.toString(w));



    while (n.size() > 0) {

        String smallest = null;
        for (String f : n) {
            if (smallest == null || smallest.compareTo(f)>0) {
                smallest = f;

            }
        }
        answer.add(smallest);
        n.remove(smallest);
```

the expected output is:

```
12
15
17
1327
1327
17
15
12
```

The code output instead is:

```
12
1327
15
17
17
15
1327
12
```

The reason it prints reverse as well is because of another part of code and is supposed to be that way. I debugged it already and the compareTO(f)>0 for some reason giving the wrong int for 1327. Does anyone know what Im doing wrong?

Comment: You're not comparing integers. You're comparing *strings*. "1327" is an earlier string than "15". Try creating a `List<Integer>` instead...

Comment: You are sorting strings (i.e. in alphabetical order), not numbers...

Comment: It's completely correct. "1327" < "15"

Comment: how is 1327 < 15 i can change it to Integers and itll work but can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

actually, the program runs correctly!!
You use String.compareTo to compare Integers...thus, 15<12345 but '12345'<'15'
You have to adjust your code to use Integers if you want to sort them.

PS: to avoid writing your algorithm, you can use `Collections.sort();`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> answer = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> n = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = 1327;
    int x = 17;
    int y = 15;
    int z = 12;
    n.add(x);
    n.add(y);
    n.add(z);
    n.add(w);

    while (n.size() > 0) {

        Integer smallest = null;
        for (Integer f : n) {
            if (smallest == null || smallest>f) {
                smallest = f;

            }
        }
        answer.add(smallest);
        n.remove(smallest);
```